# Pinescript Plot a series of custome values

Tags: plot, pine-script

so i have a list with values and i want at start 202202-02 to plot the first value on the first candle and then second value on second candle and so on... all together it should get a line with all the values.

But i always get the same error when i want to plot the script on the chart "Study error"
Chart: symbol = KO , daily timeframe

```
//@version=5
indicator("Plot Values", overlay=true)

// Define the list of values
float[] values = array.from(60.56, 60.95, 61.36, 61.11, 61.41, 61.78, 61.32, 61.36, 60.7, 60.69, 60.82, 60.87, 61.64, 62.2, 62.25, 61.84, 61.02, 62.15, 62.21, 62.06, 62.29, 62.4, 62.51, 61.62, 59.79, 59.28, 58.41, 58.11, 58.38, 59.14, 59.34, 59.8, 59.99, 60.35, 60.63, 60.49, 60.79, 61.25, 61.66, 61.97, 62.12, 62.05, 62.55, 62.55, 62.5, 62.87, 63.22, 63.6, 63.73, 64.24, 64.54, 64.84, 64.59, 64.89, 65.55, 65.96, 65.52, 65.78, 65.33, 65.47, 65.92, 65.11, 64.08, 63.46, 64.43, 64.48, 64.64, 64.62, 64.24, 64.28, 64.42, 65.22, 65.68, 65.74, 62.93, 61.12, 61.03, 62.16, 63.31, 63.78, 64.1, 64.46, 63.79, 63.35, 63.58, 63.2, 63.0, 63.15, 62.99, 62.25, 61.73, 61.49, 60.09, 59.83, 59.36, 59.4, 60.2, 60.79, 61.46, 62.44, 62.73, 62.45, 62.62, 62.8, 63.78, 63.47, 63.43, 63.11, 63.13, 63.01, 62.8, 62.54, 62.32, 62.43, 61.95, 62.31, 61.81, 61.53, 61.57, 61.95, 62.73, 62.9, 63.62, 63.96, 64.31, 63.89, 63.91, 63.76, 63.53, 63.18, 63.1, 63.44, 63.3, 63.55, 64.14, 64.69, 64.81, 65.06, 65.13, 64.55, 64.38, 64.37, 64.55, 63.66, 63.09, 62.51, 62.01, 62.01, 61.48, 61.29, 61.92, 62.04, 62.21, 62.39, 61.2, 60.95, 60.07, 59.74, 59.9, 59.9, 59.59, 59.39, 58.9, 58.26, 57.1, 57.03, 56.74, 56.3, 56.51, 56.68, 56.41, 55.56, 54.91, 54.59, 54.52, 54.9, 55.5, 55.18, 55.49, 56.08, 56.01, 55.43, 55.76, 56.88, 58.16, 58.92, 59.3, 60.2, 59.98, 59.77, 59.18, 58.93, 59.13, 59.35, 59.51, 59.05, 60.18, 60.89, 60.79, 60.69, 60.59, 60.66, 60.96, 61.65, 62.08, 62.42, 62.59, 62.66, 62.55, 63.2, 63.57, 64.05, 63.69, 63.54, 63.54, 63.71, 63.36, 63.74, 63.89, 63.95, 63.43, 63.01, 62.91, 62.83, 63.43, 63.37, 63.65, 64.0, 63.73, 63.87, 63.71, 63.24, 63.04, 62.52, 63.06, 62.78, 62.38, 62.15, 61.57, 61.48, 61.6, 60.5, 60.02, 60.06, 60.16, 60.4, 60.73, 60.78, 60.6)

a = 0.0

start = timestamp(2022, 2, 2)
if time >= start
    for i = 0 to 250
        a := array.get(values, i)
        
            
plot(series = a, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start with an index of 0, so since your array has 250 values in it you need to loop up to 249. The easiest way is to use the array size and subtract 1. Here's a working version of your code

```
// Define the list of values
float[] values = array.from(60.56, 60.95, 61.36, 61.11, 61.41, 61.78, 61.32, 61.36, 60.7, 60.69, 60.82, 60.87, 61.64, 62.2, 62.25, 61.84, 61.02, 62.15, 62.21, 62.06, 62.29, 62.4, 62.51, 61.62, 59.79, 59.28, 58.41, 58.11, 58.38, 59.14, 59.34, 59.8, 59.99, 60.35, 60.63, 60.49, 60.79, 61.25, 61.66, 61.97, 62.12, 62.05, 62.55, 62.55, 62.5, 62.87, 63.22, 63.6, 63.73, 64.24, 64.54, 64.84, 64.59, 64.89, 65.55, 65.96, 65.52, 65.78, 65.33, 65.47, 65.92, 65.11, 64.08, 63.46, 64.43, 64.48, 64.64, 64.62, 64.24, 64.28, 64.42, 65.22, 65.68, 65.74, 62.93, 61.12, 61.03, 62.16, 63.31, 63.78, 64.1, 64.46, 63.79, 63.35, 63.58, 63.2, 63.0, 63.15, 62.99, 62.25, 61.73, 61.49, 60.09, 59.83, 59.36, 59.4, 60.2, 60.79, 61.46, 62.44, 62.73, 62.45, 62.62, 62.8, 63.78, 63.47, 63.43, 63.11, 63.13, 63.01, 62.8, 62.54, 62.32, 62.43, 61.95, 62.31, 61.81, 61.53, 61.57, 61.95, 62.73, 62.9, 63.62, 63.96, 64.31, 63.89, 63.91, 63.76, 63.53, 63.18, 63.1, 63.44, 63.3, 63.55, 64.14, 64.69, 64.81, 65.06, 65.13, 64.55, 64.38, 64.37, 64.55, 63.66, 63.09, 62.51, 62.01, 62.01, 61.48, 61.29, 61.92, 62.04, 62.21, 62.39, 61.2, 60.95, 60.07, 59.74, 59.9, 59.9, 59.59, 59.39, 58.9, 58.26, 57.1, 57.03, 56.74, 56.3, 56.51, 56.68, 56.41, 55.56, 54.91, 54.59, 54.52, 54.9, 55.5, 55.18, 55.49, 56.08, 56.01, 55.43, 55.76, 56.88, 58.16, 58.92, 59.3, 60.2, 59.98, 59.77, 59.18, 58.93, 59.13, 59.35, 59.51, 59.05, 60.18, 60.89, 60.79, 60.69, 60.59, 60.66, 60.96, 61.65, 62.08, 62.42, 62.59, 62.66, 62.55, 63.2, 63.57, 64.05, 63.69, 63.54, 63.54, 63.71, 63.36, 63.74, 63.89, 63.95, 63.43, 63.01, 62.91, 62.83, 63.43, 63.37, 63.65, 64.0, 63.73, 63.87, 63.71, 63.24, 63.04, 62.52, 63.06, 62.78, 62.38, 62.15, 61.57, 61.48, 61.6, 60.5, 60.02, 60.06, 60.16, 60.4, 60.73, 60.78, 60.6)

a = 0.0

start = timestamp(2022, 2, 2)
if time >= start
    for i = 0 to values.size()-1
        a := array.get(values, i)
        
            
plot(series = a, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: i tried it but exept that for that you cant take more than 999 values into array.from() it still does only plot the first value and also the wrong value